# Best way to create an NSArray of NSNumbers from int **

Tags: nsarray, nsnumber

I am using a library that returns a a series of ints using a parameter that looks like:

int ** outList

What is the best way to take that and wrap it in a bunch of NSNumber objects (and perhaps an NSArray to hold them)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no shortcut, that I know of. You can write something like this:

```
int **outList = ...
int count = ...
NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:count];

for (int idx = 0; idx < count; idx++)
  [result addObject:@(outList[idx])];
```

Hope it helps!